# Swiftui multiple binding for a single Slider

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

How can I bind multiple variables to a single Slider is SwiftUI?

I would like to have 1 slider that changes 2 variables, one in a range from 1 to 5 and another from 1000 to 1200. Or any workaround for this?

So when variable1 = 1, variable2 should be 1000 and when variable1 = 5, variable2 should be 1200 and everything in between.
Thanks (I'm new to programming)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var variable1 = 1.0
    @State private var variable2 = 1000.0
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Slider(value: $variable1, in: 1...5, step: 0.25)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is, instead of using a second `@State` variable, to use a computed property:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var variable1 = 1.0
    
    private var variable1Range = 1.0...5.0
    private var variable2Range = 1000.0...1200.0
    
    var variable2 : Double {
        floatingMap(minRange: variable1Range.lowerBound, maxRange: variable1Range.upperBound, minDomain: variable2Range.lowerBound, maxDomain: variable2Range.upperBound, value: variable1)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Variable 1: \(variable1)")
            Text("Variable 2: \(variable2)")
            Slider(value: $variable1, in: variable1Range, step: 0.25)
            
        }
    }
}

func floatingMap<T:FloatingPoint>(minRange:T, maxRange:T, minDomain:T, maxDomain:T, value:T) -> T {
    return minDomain + (maxDomain - minDomain) * (value - minRange) / (maxRange - minRange)
}
```

If you truly need two `@State` variables, you could use `onChange` to watch `variable1` and assign a new value on `variable2` based on its value:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var variable1 = 1.0
    @State private var variable2 = 1000.0
    
    private var variable1Range = 1.0...5.0
    private var variable2Range = 1000.0...1200.0
    
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Variable 1: \(variable1)")
            Text("Variable 2: \(variable2)")
            Slider(value: $variable1, in: variable1Range, step: 0.25)
        }.onChange(of: variable1) { variable1 in
            variable2 = floatingMap(minRange: variable1Range.lowerBound, maxRange: variable1Range.upperBound, minDomain: variable2Range.lowerBound, maxDomain: variable2Range.upperBound, value: variable1)
        }
    }
}

func floatingMap<T:FloatingPoint>(minRange:T, maxRange:T, minDomain:T, maxDomain:T, value:T) -> T {
    return minDomain + (maxDomain - minDomain) * (value - minRange) / (maxRange - minRange)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works fine.